# Change 2nd page text on button click

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the

text of second html page on button click from first page.Need just a simple example

With JavaScript
<button onclick="window.location.href='index.html?image=images/armac1.png'" >Invisible button</button>

Comment: Perhaps reword your question to say "How to get query params via javascript"

Comment: Quite mysterious - I'll try to guess what do you want. Let me know if I right :)

If you want to return different page content for different users then, I guess, you need backend that _generate_ pages. I mean it is not just static html files. It is node.js or PHP or something. BUT! You did not specify what backend you want to use, so I cannot answer what you should do. Please, tell me some more about your backend.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.